# AVAudioPlayer playing overtime viewcont. loads [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

In my mainmenuviewcontroller in `viewDidLoad`, I tell it to play a background song. Problem is, when a user goes to another view and then goes back to the main menu, it starts playing the song again, and the two copies overlap. I tried to put this in the `viewDidLoad` but it didn't work

```
if themePlayer.playing == false {

themePlayer.prepareToPlay()

themePlayer.play()

}
```

It just kind of ignores the if condition and plays anyways. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`-viewDidLoad` will only run when the view is initially loaded. Since your player is still playing the song when you navigate away from the `mainmenuviewcontroller` this indicates that the view controller is never being deallocated. Try putting the if condition in the `-viewDidAppear` or `-viewWillAppear` method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    if themePlayer == nil {
        // Either it's the first time this view is loaded, or themePlayer was deallocated
        let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("pres song", withExtension: "mp3") 
        themePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: nil) 
        themePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1 
        themePlayer.volume = 0.1
        themePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        themePlayer.play()
    }

    if themePlayer.playing == false {
            themePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            themePlayer.play()
        }
}
```

If in doubt in the future on if something is being called, use [breakpoints](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode) and step through the code.

Comment: I tried both viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear. I still get the same problem. When I navigate back to the main menu another copy of the sound clip starts playing on top of the original and it sounds like two songs being played at the same time.

Comment: Here is the code: 'override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated);
        
        //theme music
        let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("pres song", withExtension: "mp3")
        
        themePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: nil)
        
        themePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        
        themePlayer.volume = 0.1

        
        if themePlayer.playing == false {
            
            themePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            
            themePlayer.play()
            
            
        }
    }'

Comment: You are reinitializing the player in viewDidAppear, which I suspect is why it will play the song again in `if themePlayer.playing == false`. Before initializing themePlayer in `viewDidAppear`, check if it's already initialized as there is no point to create a new one. I'll update my answer so the code is formatted correctly.

Comment: Dang still not working. I declared the property at the top with - var themePlayer: AVAudioPlayer? and then used your code, still same problem. Man you'd think there'd be a simple way to set some kind of theme song for your app that just plays on all viewcontrollers and loops properly....

Comment: How about playing from the delegate file?